# PHP - Get URL and send to array

Tags: php, arrays, function, explode

So lets say I have a link like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/profile/alexkvazos/
```

I would like to explode the url and get this:

```
$uri = array('profile','alexkvazos');
```

What is the easiest approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
// if the url is http://www.example.com/foo/bar/wow
 function getUriSegments() {
    return explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
 }

    print_r(getUriSegments()); //returns array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar', 2=>'wow')
```

Source :- http://www.timwickstrom.com/server-side-code/php/php-get-uri-segments/

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes sure let me add

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$path_parts = parse_url('http://mywebsite.com/profile/alexkvazos/');
$uri = explode('/',trim($path_parts['path'],'/'));
print_r($uri);
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/144837)</kbd>

Comment: Here you are giving me the URL already on the parse_url function. How would I get it from the URL on the browser?

Comment: Read $_SERVER manual of PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/1003917) on how to get your URL. Grab that and into a string and pass it into the `parse_url()` function as shown. @RohitKumarChoudhary, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this piece of code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://mywebsite.com/profile/alexkvazos/';

$url = rtrim($url,'/'); // lose the trailing slash
$urlArr = explode("/", $url );
$urlArr = array_reverse( $urlArr );

echo $urlArr[0];

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use `parse_url`, I would just use `preg_split` like this:

```
$segments = preg_split('#/#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$final = array();

foreach($segments as $key => $value) {
    if($value != '') {
        $final[] = $value;
    }
}


var_dump($final);
```